# What does the underscore before the label value in Django forms mean

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have came through the `UserCreationForm` in the django source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L82).
Here is the question, if you look at both password fields you will see an underscore before the label value, I wonder what's the purpose of it, because it's not written in the documentation since I searched for it.

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': _('The two password fields didn’t match.'),
}
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    strip=False,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alias for the [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy). Indeed, at [line 19 [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L19), we see:

> ```
> from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
> ```

This will *lazily* translate the message. It means that if you render it in the template, the template will call `str(…)` on the lazy translation object. This will, depending on the activated language, provide a translated version of the label.

For more information about translations, see the [*Tranlation* section of the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translation).

Comment: A Huge Thanks for your great answer, actually i found that I read about it before during my search about localization and translations but just forgot about it, Thanks again